# User Control runs SQL Server stored procedure returns DataTable event handler error

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this user control that runs a stored procedure

```
public DataTable btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        UtilitiesClass ru = new UtilitiesClass();
        string connectionString = ru.getConnectionString();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FindCust", myConnection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust", txtCust.Text.Trim());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter ta = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ta.Fill(dt);

            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

        return (dt);
}
```

I get an error on this VS generated code:

```
this.btnFind.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnFind_Click);
```

telling me

> 'DataTable FindCustControl.btnFind_Click(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type.

I don't know where to start. I don't even understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return data table from the event responsible for handling button click.

> UPDATE

To return the datatable from the user control to the main form where user control is present, you should implement a custom event in the user control. There is a great article here:

http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/15/events.html

```js
//Generated code
this.btnFind.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnFind_Click);

//Button click handler
public void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var resultset = GetData();
  
  //Do whatever with data here
  //...
}

//Query database
public DataTable GetData()
{
  UtilitiesClass ru = new UtilitiesClass();
  string connectionString = ru.getConnectionString();

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  try
  {
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FindCust", myConnection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust", txtCust.Text.Trim());
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter ta = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ta.Fill(dt);
    myConnection.Close();

  }
  catch (Exception x)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
  }
  return (dt);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I am actually writing a user control and need to return the data table.  How can I do that if I can't do it in the click event.  Can I just return it with var(resultset = GetData()) within the click event?